# What's a good XML format to store a directed graph?

Tags: xml, coding-style, formatting

The graph is composed of many vertices each of which have some properties, and directed edges between two vertices.

What's a good XML format to store such?

```
<graph>
  <vertices>
    <vertex>
      <name>foobar</name>
      <vertexproperties>
        <vertexproperty>
          <name>p1</name>
          <value>v1</value>
        </vertexproperty>
        <vertexproperty>
          <name>p2</name>
          <value>v2</value>
        </vertexproperty>
      </vertexproperties>
    </vertex>
  </vertices>
  <edges>
    <edge>
      <startingVertex>foo<endVertex>
      <endingVertex>bar<endingVertex>
    </edge>
  </edges>
</graph>
```

Is the pair of `<vertexproperties>` and `</vertexproperties>` useful? Why?

Any other suggestions?

I'm new to XML and graph computing.

Comment: Looks fine. It really depends on what you're gonna do with the XML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the comparative that [gephi](https://gephi.org/) does on graph formats:

https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/

[Gefx](http://gexf.net/format/schema.html) is the recommended one and seems to comply with your requirements. In any case some of the others could probably work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your main aim is to render the graph visually, look at DotML which is an XML syntax for the dot language used by GraphViz.

I'm not a great fan of abstract property syntax, that is elements like

```
<property name="foo" value="bar"/>
```

XML was designed to be extensible, so why not use

```
<foo>bar</foo>
```

One reason people use the first form is that they think they can write a "tighter" schema to keep it valid. But you can write a schema for the latter form too (using wildcards) and it's just as useful.

Comment: So the code in my original post uses the second style and is better for the reasons you said?

Comment: What do you think about the necessity and/or usefulness of having `<vertexproperties>` and `</vertexproperties>`?

Comment: It's easier to iterate over and extend, so for example you could add an extra property in a database table that represents key-value pairs, and voila, it shows up all nice and valid without changing XML schemas as well.

Comment: But my point is, you can write a schema that allows arbitrary element names (using wildcards), you don't have to resort to abstract property syntax in order to retain extensibility.